# Resolving a Promise in Protractor

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

Strange issue I don't understand yet when trying to resolve (fulfill) my promise in Protractor.

Something is very wrong with the line `deferred.fulfill(rowData);`, as it's NOT returning the `row` data as I would expect.

In other words, `rowData.count()` in the lower function is fine, but when returned `row.count()` is failing.

```js
this.gridFunction = function (summaryData){


  var rowData = getGridRowByText(gridRows, name, text);
  
  rowData.then(function (row) {            
     // ** THROWS ERROR ** TypeError: row.count is not a function
     expect(row.count()).toEqual(3);

     row.map(function (cell) {  
        // iterate cell contents, compare with "summaryData"
     });

  });
}


 function getGridRowByText(gridRows, grid, text) {
        var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
                
        var parentId = getParId();

        parentId.getAttribute("id").then(function (parentId) {

            // i.e. jquery $('.grid-wrapper.fluid-wrapper #rowId_21')
            var sel = '.grid-wrapper.fluid-wrapper #' + parentId;
            
            var rowData = element(by.css(sel)).all(by.repeater('column in  vm.sourceData.columns'));
            
            // EXPECT SUCCESSFULL !!!
            expect(rowData.count()).toEqual(19);
            
            
            deferred.fulfill(rowData);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
};
```

Main question: am I NOT properly returning the fulfilled promise with the `rowData` object ?

*** UPDATE ***

My final solution  :

It doesn't actually solve my original problem of working with the Protractor Promise, but rather just a redesign of the logic.

```js
this.gridFunction = function (targetRowText){

  
  var result = gridRows.all(by.cssContainingText('span', targetRowText)).first();
  var parentId = result.all(by.xpath("./ancestor::div[starts-with(@id, 'rowId')]"));
        
        
  parentId.getAttribute("id").then(function (parentId) {            
      console.log('  (ROW-ID: ', parentId);
            
      // further iterations here...
  }
  
}
```

thank you,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a "deferred" object here. Just return the promise from the function:

```
function getGridRowByText(gridRows, grid, text) {
    var parentId = getParId();

    return parentId.getAttribute("id").then(function (parentId) {
        var sel = '.grid-wrapper.fluid-wrapper #' + parentId;
        return element(by.css(sel)).all(by.repeater('column in  vm.sourceData.columns'));
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
var rowData = getGridRowByText(gridRows, name, text);
expect(rowData.count()).toEqual(3);
```

---

Or, if further processing needed in the `getgridRowByText()` function:

```
function getGridRowByText(gridRows, grid, text) {
    var parentId = getParId();

    return parentId.getAttribute("id").then(function (parentId) {
        var sel = '.grid-wrapper.fluid-wrapper #' + parentId;

        var rowData = element(by.css(sel)).all(by.repeater('column in  vm.sourceData.columns'));

        // further processing here
        expect(rowData.count()).toEqual(19);

        return rowData;
    });
};
```

Comment: I actually have further processing to do. I'm comparing the "rowData" cell contents with some "summaryData" object I have previously populated. This is why I have setup a promise. Main question is: why is the fulfill not behaving as expected ? `rowData` appears to have changed.

Comment: @bob.mazzo gotcha, I think the current problem is that you are making a "deferred" which does not have the `count()` method as an `ElementArrayFinder` would have. I still think you don't need to manually make a promise and fulfill it, I've added an another sample code to demonstrate that you can still return the `rowData` from the function (note the upper-level `return` as well). Thanks.

Comment: Yes in fact I did end up tossing the additional function call earlier today. It was just too clunky. I'll review your additional solution in the morning. Many thanks, Alec.